# Comparing two functions.

Tags: functions

I've received this task from my professor to solve for an assignment, but I do not know how to prove it.

> Asume the functions f and g are so that f' and g' are continuous on
>   the interval [a,b] and f'' and g'' exist on (a, b).
>
> Asume further that f'(a) = g'(a) & f'(b) = g'(b).
>
> Prove that there is a number "c" that is an element of (a, b) so that
>   f''(c) = g''(c).

Any help/tips appreciated.

Comment: Try applying mean value theorem to $f'-g'$ in $[a,b]$.

Comment: Consider the function $f'-g'$ and the mean value theorem or Rolle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply Rolle's theorem to
$$h(x) = f'(x)-g'(x)$$